# How to insert the record the record at the specific ID in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I am newbie to android SQLite and i had a doubt about inserting records in sqlite.
How we can insert a record at the pirticular position into the sqlite 
i,e. if i am inserting first record it will goes to the first position,Then i'll skip the second record and then insert the third record and it will store as record 3 with ID 3 as shown below

```
      ID            value
      1              abc
      2                 
      3              def
      4              ghi
      5              jkl
      6
```

Like this can anyone tell me how to achieve this

Comment: What about using a 'position' column? In the select you can then order by position like 'select * from table order by position'

Comment: can you help me in detail better with code @MimmoGrottoli

Comment: do you have a fix number of rows in your table?

Comment: Yup i am having the fixed num of rows that is 7 if count was greater than 7   then data in table will be deleted and updated @Opiatefuchs

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in your database helper class and pass the parameter . Giving you a code sample . Hope it will help you

```
   public void updateTable(String catID, String data) {
    try {
        String sql = "UPDATE data_table SET column_data = " + data + " WHERE cat_id = " + catID;
        mDb.execSQL(sql);


    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "updateTable >>" + mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to create your table with 3 columns:

- _id -> unique identifier of that entry
- slot -> this is your 1 - 6 slot, you have to take care about overflow etc.
- value -> your value "abc" etc.

e.g.:

CREATE TABLE 
slots (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, slot INTEGER NOT NULL, value TEXT);

Basically you could skip the _id column, but it is used in the CursorAdapter implementation, so you would run into trouble there and it doesn't hurt you.
As text can be null, you can create a scenario as the one you described above, only your slot's integer value has to be set.